# Erro Kotlin não acha bytecode para lambda function: "Failed to find byte code for java/util/function/BiConsumer"

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, kotlin, android-gradle

Quando tento rodar meu app no celular (no emulador acontece o mesmo), ocorre o seguinte erro:

```
Error:FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong: 
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithInstantRunForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: 
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: 
Failed to find byte code for java/util/function/BiConsumer

* Try:
 Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --
 debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3m 4s
```

"Soluções" que já tentei mas não funcionaram:

- Atualizar o Android Studio (Canary 6),
- Atualizar o Kotlin (1.2.10),
- Atualizar o Gradle (3.1.0-alpha06),
- Adicionar dependência Multidex

Comment: Acredito que isto seja um problema com o `Instant Run` ao invés de ser com Kotlin. Desative o Instant Run nas configurações.

Comment: Funcionou! Mas é estranho, porque em outro PC funcionou com o Instant Run ativado...

Comment: O problema é que alguns emuladores/dispositivos não possuem suporte ao Instant Run e esse erro acontece.

Answer (score 1):

Tente desabilitar o Instant Run em

`Preferences > Build, Execution, Deployment`

[image: Android Studio Preferences]

Foi a unica coisa que funcionou pra mim!